# Entity Framework get all columns with group by

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

we are migrating reports from SQL to EF. In the process I just stumbled over the following query:

```
SELECT
    pl.clientid,
    pl.loginname,
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            DISTINCT
            s.clientid,
            s.doctype
        FROM
            Specifications s
    ) A
    INNER JOIN portal_logins pl ON A.clientid = pl.clientid
WHERE
    A.clientid != '0'
GROUP BY
    A.clientid,
    A.doctype
```

My current solution is the following

```
return await _nfContext.Specifications
    .Select( x => new
    {
        Clientid = x.Clientid,
        Doctype = x.Doctype
    })
    .Distinct()
    .Join(
        _nfContext.PortalLogins,
        s => s.Clientid,
        p => p.Clientid,
        (spec, login) => new
        {
                loginName = login.Loginname,
                clientId  = spec.Clientid,
                doctype   = spec.Doctype
        }
    )
    .Where(x => x.clientId != "0")
    .GroupBy(c => new
    {
        c.clientId,
        c.doctype,
        c.loginName
    })
    .Select(result => new TotalActiveConnections
    {
        ActiveConnections = result.Count(),
        ClientId = result.Key.clientId,
        LoginName = result.Key.loginName
    })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.ActiveConnections)
    .ToListAsync()
    .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

My problem is, I need all three columns as described in the Group by, but I don't want to group by login name. Does anyone have an idea what I can do? Thanks in advance for the help....

Comment: "we are migrating reports from SQL to EF" - uhhh, what? Linq-to-EF doesn't replace or supplant SQL, it's an abstraction _over SQL_ - so what are you _really_ trying to accomplish here? (And personally, I wouldn't use Linq-to-EF for queries for reports or in reporting systems because Linq is not as expressive as SQL (e.g. no windowing functions, CTEs, etc) and EF is meant for OLTP, not OLAP - so I'm curious why you're doing this.

Comment: *but I don't want to group by login name* - Why? Looks like MySQL and it's quirks.

Comment: HI are you running on MVC5 or .net core?

Comment: You should pretty much never use `Join()` in EF, use `Include()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just use `Min` or `Max` to get any random `login` value

```cs
    .GroupBy(c => new
    {
        c.clientId,
        c.doctype
    })
    .Select(result => new TotalActiveConnections
    {
        ActiveConnections = result.Count(),
        ClientId = result.Key.clientId,
        LoginName = result.Min(g => g.loginName),
    })
```

Presumably it worked in SQL because you were using MySQL/MariaDB and did not have `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` turned on.